# Service Fabric, determine if specific actor exists

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

We are using Azure Service Fabric and are using actors to model specific devices, using the id of the device as the `ActorId`. Service Fabric will instantiate a new actor instance when we request an actor for a given id if it is not already instantiated, but I cannot seem to find an api that allows me to query if a specific device id already has an instantiated actor.

I understand that there might be some distributed/timing issues in obtaining the point-in-time truth but for our specific purpose, we do not need a hard realtime answer to this but can settle for a best guess. We would just like to, in theory, contact the current primary for the specific partition resolved by the `ActorId` and get back whether or not the device has an instantiated actor.

Ideally it is a fast/performant call, essentially faster than e.g. instantiating the actor and calling a method to understand if it has been initialized correctly and is not just an "empty" actor.

You can use the `ActorServiceProxy` to iterate through the information for a specific partition but that does not seem to be a very performant way of obtaining the information.

Anyone with insights into this?

Comment: Currently there is no way to do this. A workaround might be to have an actor store its ID in an azure table , stateful service or other store and call that store to get this information. You won't have to activate deactived actors to get their existance this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only official way you can check if the actor has been activated in any Service Partition previously is using the `ActorServiceProxy` query, like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-enumerate):

```
IActorService actorServiceProxy = ActorServiceProxy.Create(
    new Uri("fabric:/MyApp/MyService"), partitionKey);

ContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
do
{
    PagedResult<ActorInformation> page = await actorServiceProxy.GetActorsAsync(continuationToken, cancellationToken);

    var actor = page.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ActorId == idToFind);

    continuationToken = page.ContinuationToken;
}
while (continuationToken != null);
```

By the nature of SF Actors, they are virtual, that means they always exist, even though you didn't activated then previously, so it make a bit harder to do this check.

As you said, it is not performant to query all actors, so, the other workarounds you could try is:

1. Store the IDs in a Reliable Dictionary elsewhere, every time an Actor is activated you raise an event and insert the ActorIDs in the Dictionary if not there yet.

   - You can use the `OnActivateAsync()` actor event to notify it's creation, or
   - You can use the custom actor factory in the ActorService to register actor activation
   - You can store the dictionary in another actor, or another StatefulService
2. Create a property in the actor that is set by the actor itself when it is activated.

   - The `OnActivateAsync()` check if this property has been set before
   - If not set yet, you set a new value and store in a variable (a non persisted value) to say the actor is new
   - Whenever you interact with actor you set this to indicate it is not new anymore
   - The next activation, the property will be already set, and nothing should happen.
3. Create a custom IActorStateProvider to do the same as mentioned in the option 2, instead of handle it in the actor it will handle a level underneath it. Honestly I think it is a bit of work, would only be handy if you have to do the same for many actor types, the option 1 and 2 would be much easier.
4. Do as *Peter Bons* Suggested, store the ActorID outside the ActorService, like in a DB, *I would only suggest this option if you have to check this from outside the cluster*.

.

The following snipped can help you if you want to manage these events outside the actor.

```
private static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<NetCoreActorService>(
           (context, actorType) => new ActorService(context, actorType,
                    new Func<ActorService, ActorId, ActorBase>((actorService, actorId) =>
                    {
                        RegisterActor(actorId);//The custom method to register the actor if new
                        return (ActorBase)Activator.CreateInstance(actorType.ImplementationType, actorService, actorId);
                    })
                )).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ActorEventSource.Current.ActorHostInitializationFailed(e.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}

private static void RegisterActor(ActorId actorId) 
{
    //Here you will put the logic to register elsewhere the actor creation
}
```

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, as this outlines possible ways to make something work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could create a stateful `DeviceActorStatusActor` which would be notified (called) by `DeviceActor` as soon as it's created. (Share the ActorId for correlation.)

Depending on your needs you can also register multiple Actors with the same status-tracking actor.

You'll have great performance and near real-time information.